# CASE WHEN breaks with condition that never happens

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a script that has recently broken on me.

In it, I have a CASE statement which handles a code column. When the ProductIdentifier is 'ABC', the third character is a number. In other cases, it's not.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN risk.PRODUCTIDENTIFIER = 'ABC' AND DATEADD(y, CAST(SUBSTRING(risk.BenefitLabel, 3, 1) AS tinyint), risk.BenefitStartDate) >= DATEADD(m, 1, CAST(CAST('202109'/100 AS Char(4)) + '-' + SUBSTRING('202109', 5, 6) + '-01' AS DATE)) THEN 1
        WHEN risk.ConvertedPolicyNo IS NOT NULL
                AND DATEADD(y, 1, conversions.BenefitStartDate) >= DATEADD(m, 1, CAST(CAST('202109'/100 AS Char(4)) + '-' + SUBSTRING('202109', 5, 6) + '-01' AS DATE)) THEN 1 
        END AS ADB_FLAG
FROM 
    risk
    LEFT JOIN conversions 
        ON risk.ConvertedPolicyNo = conversions.PolicyNumber 
        AND risk.ConvertedPolicyInsuredNo = conversions.PolicyInsuredNo
WHERE 
    risk.Productidentifier NOT IN ('ABC', 'XYZ')
```

The weird thing is that the above query fails, giving the following error message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'F' to data type tinyint.

But if I remove either condition from the CASE statement, it works just fine. This is especially odd to me, since the first condition is impossible due to the limits in the 'WHERE' clause.

My understanding is that SQL is supposed to evaluate the WHERE clause before the SELECT clause. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Simple, you have a row in your table where `SUBSTRING(risk.BenefitLabel, 3, 1)` contains an "F".

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works when the second CASE condition is removed

Comment: The rows that SQL Server decides it needs to evaluate the case expression against is something unknown to us mere mortals. So firstly, the where clause doesn't protect you against it attempting to evaluate against a row that won't even be returns. Secondly changing any aspect of the query can change the rows it evaluates.

Comment: What's the common solution to such a scenario then? (How) do you force lazy evaluation in such cases?

Comment: Depends on the data you are storing, but as simple solution might be to add `AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(risk.BenefitLabel, 3, 1)) = 1` to that branch of your case. Keep in mind that `ISNUMERIC` isn't perfect, but its often good enough.

Comment: @DanielV see my answer below

Comment: You're doing things the hard way for no benefit. This `CAST(CAST('202109'/100 AS Char(4)) + '-' + SUBSTRING('202109', 5, 6) + '-01' AS DATE)` can be reduced to `CAST('20210901' AS DATE)`. I've never seen anyone cast a constant string to an int, divide it by 100, and then cast it back to string just to remove the last 2 characters. For that matter, why use a 6 character constant when you only need the first 4 characters?

Comment: @SMor - yeah, those values are originally table variables. I've set them to constants in this query when trying to narrow down the problem. Didn't realise that YYYYMMDD worked in SQL though (background is R where it's YYYY-MM-DD unless specified otherwise), but I'll definitely tidy that up

Comment: @DanielV - another possible workaround: 
Replace:   CAST(SUBSTRING(risk.BenefitLabel, 3, 1) AS tinyint)
with:   COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(risk.BenefitLabel, 3, 1)), 0)

Comment: See another example of expression reordering here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/301650/220697

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server is free to evaluate the predicates in your WHERE clause much later than your projections in the SELECT. If you absolutely must have the data filtered so as to remove erroneous rows, then you may use a hack such as a CTE with an ORDER BY and a TOP N clause. Just make the TOP N large enough to ensure that you will get all of your rows. When I resort to this (typically for JSON use cases), I usually use the maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer, or TOP 2147483647 in conjunction with an arbitrary ORDER BY clause.

An alternative is to place the conforming rows into a temporary table or a table variable, then query from that.

There is no way to force a standard SQL statement to evaluate the predicate in advance of the CASE expression.